# Finding the difference in "the shop opens/is open at 8:30am to 9:30pm"

Tags: difference

Is there a difference between the two sentences:

> 1. The shop opens at 8:30am to 9:30pm.
> 2. The shop is open at 8:30am to 9:30pm.

Answer (score 3):

There can be a huge difference between the two sentences, but your first sentence is not quite correct.

> The shop opens at 8:30am to 9:30am

would usually be said as

> The shop opens between 8:30am and 9:30am

if the speaker is not sure of the actual opening time. Otherwise only a single time is usually given for an *opening time*

> The shop opens at 8:30am.
>   By 9:00am the shop is open.

When speaking about the duration of being open one would say

> The shop is open **between** 8:30am **and** 9:30am.

which is a bit short for store hours since it is only an hour.

Your first sentence seems to refer to the **event** of the shop opening its doors for business, whereas your second sentence

> The shop is open at 8:30am to 9:30pm.

refers to **duration** of when the shop opens, 8:30am, and when it closes, 9:30am, but is usually stated as

> The shop is open at 8:30am **until** 9:30pm.
>   The shop **opens** at 8:30am and **closes** at 9:30am.